# Best way of handling object composed of two other objects in terms of hiding implementation details?

Tags: java, design-patterns, law-of-demeter

For instance, I  have a class named Car which contains of two fields of type  AdminPart and PassengerPart correspondingly.

For client code using my code I want the client code to be able to do `car.getLicense()` and not `car.getAdminPart().getLicense()`. This of course is implemented as `getLicense()` in Car which in turn calls the relevant getter. Same for setters.

Is there a best practice for this? Something I've overlooked?

Comment: What do you mean for client code? Who is the client and how access to this object?

Comment: Is `getlicense()` a private method of AdminPart?

Comment: If you explain well the application structure I can explain my idea... I think you are little bit confused

Comment: Just don't implement a getAdminPart method for the Car class...

Comment: @user2004685 yup, it's a private method.

Comment: @AndreaCatania there is actually no car in the application, this is an example that doesn't violate any NDAs :)  Thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, but I am not trying to prevent the client code from use getAdminPart, just want to implement a better way for it to perform the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem sounds like it's related to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (I added the tag to your question). It's not really a *best practice* -- many have claimed it's not really a "law" but rather an heuristic ("suggestion") that strives to reduce coupling in the same direction as information hiding. My favorite explanation is [The Paperboy, the Wallet, and the Law of Demeter](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/demeter-method/LawOfDemeter/paper-boy/demeter.pdf).

*Encapsulation* states that clients of `Car` should not know the details of how a car is designed. Otherwise, if you change those details, the client code could break (and you usually want to provide stable APIs to clients). If you allow clients to do `car.getAdminPart().getLicense()` you are revealing the details of the object, violating the principle of information hiding and encapsulation.

Here's a UML diagram that explains the two ways:

[image: UML class diagram]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was planning to do as stated in the question. Was wondering whether there is a prettier solution/things to take into account that I am missing. Thanks !